# What is the fastest way to compare two RGB colors in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, graphics

If I need to compare only RGB components, is there anything faster then this?

```
bool ColorChanged(Color a, Color b)
{
    return a.ToArgb() != b.ToArgb();
}
```

In our code this method is called millions of times and I am wondering if it can be optimized. Obviously, comparing individual RGB values isn't faster.

**EDIT:** Here is my test based on SneakyTactician sample, the result is somewhat surprising: direct color comparison wins!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int len = 10000000;

   Color[] colors1 = new Color[len];
   Color[] colors2 = new Color[len];

   Random rand = new Random();

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      colors1[i] = Color.FromArgb((int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255));
      colors2[i] = Color.FromArgb((int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255));
   }

   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      ColorChanged1(colors1[i], colors2[i]);
   }

   sw.Stop();

   Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

   sw.Reset();
   sw.Start();

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      ColorChanged2(colors1[i], colors2[i]);
   }

   sw.Stop();

   Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

   sw.Reset();
   sw.Start();

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      ColorChanged3(colors1[i], colors2[i]);
   }

   sw.Stop();

   Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged3: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

static bool ColorChanged1(Color a, Color b)
{
   return a.ToArgb() != b.ToArgb();
}

static bool ColorChanged2(Color a, Color b)
{
   return a != b;
}

static bool ColorChanged3(Color a, Color b)
{
   return a.ToKnownColor() != b.ToKnownColor();
}
```

Results:

```
ColorChanged1: 206 ms
ColorChanged2: 172 ms
ColorChanged3: 159 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your bottleneck and you're not determining the colors with `Bitmap.GetPixel()`?

Comment: I doubt there is anything faster than [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1f25b4614bb23053), so if there is a performance issue, you have to search somewhere else(use a profiler).

Comment: You do realize you're also comparing the Alpha channel using that code, whereas in your statement you say you only need to compare RGB components.

Comment: If, for your purposes, you only need to compare the RGB values, the above code is broken, as it will also compare alpha values, reporting two colors as not equal if their R, G, and B components are equal but their A values differ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  _I doubt there is anything faster_ how you explain SneakyTactician's result?

Comment: @Toshi: `ToArgb` uses the `Value` property which does lil bit mpre than the other `ToKnownColor`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,12ca5f63494272d3

Comment: If you are using this to compare 2 large images in the same pixel format, it will probably be faster to call `LockBits` and directly compare the byte data.

Comment: @adv12: we don't use the Alpha component, therefore it always has the default value (255).

Comment: Any comment on my test results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you store your colors as text?

Comparing text would be faster than comparing a Color object and calling the ToArgb method every time.

So do this instead:

```
bool ColorChanged2(string a, string b)
{
    return a != b;
}
```

See the following code ... comparing strings is usually twice as fast.

```
    string runTest()
    {
        int howMany = 1000000;

        Color c1 = Color.Red;
        Color c2 = Color.Green;
        string c3 = "FF0000";
        string c4 = "00FF00";

        string result = "";
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();


        // Compare using Color object
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            bool response = ColorChanged1(c1, c2);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        result += "Compare Color objects" + Environment.NewLine;
        result += "Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        result += "" + Environment.NewLine;


        // Compare strings
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            bool response = ColorChanged2(c3, c4);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        result += "Compare strings" + Environment.NewLine;
        result += "Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        result += "" + Environment.NewLine;


        return result;
    }

    bool ColorChanged1(Color a, Color b)
    {
        return a.ToArgb() != b.ToArgb();
    }

    bool ColorChanged2(string a, string b)
    {
        return a != b;
    }
```

**Results**

Compare Color objects
Elapsed: 00:00:00.0611088

Compare strings
Elapsed: 00:00:00.0285529

Comment: please always use `Stopwatch` to measure ticks

Comment: @Toshi; thanks for the tip, the code looks cleaner now

Comment: And please make so many iterations that the actual processing time is in the order of seconds. Here you have ~60ms vs ~30ms. Such short times are very susceptible to the CPU getting interrupted by other system tasks. At these time scales the variability between runs is probably on par with the measured time.

Comment: @Juan: This is unbelievable. I would never bet on this! I cannot use strings but you gave me a new point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little benchmarking on a few various color comparison methods. They might not all be exactly what you want, but maybe they will help someone else out in the future.

Test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int I = 0;
        int i = 0;

        List<Color> Colors1 = new List<Color>();
        List<Color> Colors2 = new List<Color>();

        while (i != 1000)
        {
            Colors1.Add(RandomColor());
            Colors2.Add(RandomColor());
            i++;
        }

        Stopwatch a = new Stopwatch();

        a.Start();

        while (I != 1000)
        {
            ColorChanged1(Colors1.ElementAt(I), Colors2.ElementAt(I));
            I++;
        }

        a.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged1: " + a.Elapsed.ToString());

        a.Reset();
        a.Start();

        I = 0;

        while (I != 1000)
        {
            ColorChanged2(Colors1.ElementAt(I), Colors2.ElementAt(I));
            I++;
        }

        a.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged2: " + a.Elapsed.ToString());

        a.Reset();
        a.Start();

        I = 0;

        while (I != 1000)
        {
            ColorChanged3(Colors1.ElementAt(I), Colors2.ElementAt(I));
            I++;
        }

        a.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("ColorChanged3: " + a.Elapsed.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Color RandomColor()
    {
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        Random random = new Random();
        KnownColor rcolor = (KnownColor)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));

        return Color.FromKnownColor(rcolor);
    }

    static bool ColorChanged1(Color a, Color b)
    {
        return a.ToArgb() != b.ToArgb();
    }

    static bool ColorChanged2(Color a, Color b)
    {
        return a != b;
    }

    static bool ColorChanged3(Color a, Color b)
    {
        return a.ToKnownColor() != b.ToKnownColor();
    }
```

Results:

ColorChanged1: 00:00:00.0142920

ColorChanged2: 00:00:00.0001769

ColorChanged3: 00:00:00.0001609